Chronology of Peter's 'Eat and Kill' Vision and Paul rebuking Peter?
I've searched at decent length and I'm finding many opposing viewpoints on this.  I'm trying to see what the chronology is between four events, though two are my primary concern:

Peter's Eat and Kill Vision / Visit to Cornelius and Proclamation of Gentiles not being unclean (Acts 10)
Paul rebuking Peter for not associating with Gentiles (Galatians 2)
Peter recounting his vision to the Jerusalem church and swaying them about Gentiles (Acts 11)
The Jerusalem Council meeting (Acts 15)

I'm mainly concerned with whether Peter's 'eat and kill' vision preceded or followed Paul rebuking him.  I'm trying to answer whether Peter lapsed on his beliefs about the Gentiles.
To me, it seems more likely that the vision came before the rebuke, given the combination of two things.

Galatians 2:12 mentions how Peter previously was eating with Gentiles but then altered his behavior because of the circumcision party.
Acts 10 records Peter saying to Cornelius, "You yourselves know how unlawful it is for a Jew to associate with or visit anyone of another nation, but God has shown me that I should not call any person common or unclean."

Don't the Acts 10 words to Cornelius, and the whole vision+interpretation itself, indicate this is a 'first time' sort of thing for Peter?  It seems that way.  And if so (that this is his initial time coming to the full realization and eating with/visiting Gentiles) wouldn't that mean all of this MUST precede the rebuke?
Otherwise, if we interpret the events with the rebuke coming first, we would have what seems illogical.  That would be put Peter eating with Gentiles (mentioned by Paul in Gal 2:12) BEFORE having his first realization about how Gentiles should be eaten with/visited (Acts 10).
Any help on this is appreciated.  I've tried looking at multiple timelines for both Paul and Peter's lives with conflicting info.  However, it seems to me that ultimately Peter's 'first time eating with/visiting Gentiles' has to come before the "he was eating with Gentiles" in Galatians 2.  Of course there could be a time gap between Paul seeing him eating with Gentiles and the rebuke for altered behavior, but that wouldn't affect that the vision preceded the rebuke.
Thanks for any help.

+1 Good question. But it is not illogical  that Peter would eat with Gentiles prior to his vision.  The Council of Jerusalem allowed Gentile Christians to eat non-kosher food but dot not say that Jewish Christians should do so. The issue of table-fellowship was not settled.  Some Jews (like the "men from James") would not eat with Gentiles, but others would indeed eat with them, but refrain from eating un-kosher food.

The purpose of Peter's dream was to prepare him for what was about to happen through Paul.  The rebuke came after Peter was made aware of the administration that Christ ascended had appointed to Paul.  This is when Peter (Cephas) and Paul 'shook hands' (the right hand of fellowship) and agreed that Peter would take the gospel of the circumcision to the Jews and Paul would take the gospel of the uncircumcision to the Gentiles (Gal 2:7-9).
The rebuke (later in Antioch) was due to Peter bringing new Gentile believers back under the law with circumcision (Gal 2:11-16).  Paul is retelling the series of events that first included the 'hand shake', and then the rebuke.  The Council meeting is when Peter recalls his vision (Acts 15:7), which without him doing so would have ended the gospel of God's grace as administered through Paul.
The timeline would then be:

Peter's vision (simultaneous to what Paul was already doing, but unbeknownst to Peter at the time)
The Jerusalem Council
Peter recounting his vision
Paul's rebuke of Peter

Peter then did "lapse" in his newly revealed beliefs regarding Gentiles having direct access to God without first having to go through Israel, as he did mistakenly began to bring Jewish law as a requirement for new Gentile believers, whose good news is actually salvation by grace through having faith alone, without any required works of the law (Eph 2:8-9).

+1.  Good, simple answer.

I'm upvoting the answer and competent in well expressed, although I happen to answer it differently.

The answer depends in part on whether the Council of Jerusalem in Acts 15 is the same event as the meeting between Paul and the Jerusalem Church in Gal. 2.

When they saw that I had been entrusted with the gospel to the
uncircumcised, just as Peter to the circumcised... James and Cephas
and John, who were reputed to be pillars, gave me and Barnabas their
right hands in partnership, that we should go to the Gentiles and they
to the circumcised. 10 Only, we were to be mindful of the poor, which
is the very thing I was eager to do.

It is immediately after this that Paul describes his opposition to Peter at Antioch.
The issue in Gal. 2 is whether Jewish Christians were allowed to eat with Gentile Christians. It was not whether Jewish Christians such as Peter and Paul could eat pigs, dogs, reptiles and other 'unclean' animals.
In my view, Paul's meeting in Jerusalem in Gal. 2 is the same as the Council of Jerusalem in Acts 15. This meeting settled the matter as to which food Gentile Christians could eat. But the issue of table fellowship between Jews and Gentiles had not been settled, and this resulted in Paul's opposition to Peter's policy at Antioch.
Luke's chronology says that Peter's dream came first. That is clear, but I see a problem with this. If Paul was already eating the types of food described in Acts 10, then he was already transgressing clear stipulations of the law of the Torah. He would have no reason to refuse table fellowship with Gentile Christians, for this was only one of the "traditions of [some of] the elders," not an actual Torah law.
I do not think that Peter would compromise himself so seriously by opposing the clear message of God's revelation in order to please the "men from James." So, I suggest that the ruling of James and the elders in Acts 15 actually came earlier than is indicated by Luke (or Peter's dream came later). The issue of table fellowship was not yet settled. Otherwise, we would have to picture Peter as not only disagreeing with Paul about an unsettled matter, but opposing God's message to him in Acts 10.
Conclusion: Paul's scolding of Peter came first. It was only after this that Peter received his vision.

Thank you, Dan!  +1 as well...for the varying degree of opinion ;-)  Oh, to be a fly on the wall at that meeting!

In my view, "table fellowship" does not seem to be an issue in Paul's teaching. In Romans 14, Gentiles and Jews can eat at the same table, each choose their own food without passing judgment on one another. He states in Romans 14:17, "For the kingdom of God is not a matter of eating and drinking, but of righteousness, peace and joy in the Holy Spirit." According to Romans 14:22-23, Jews can eat pork if they believe it is clean, but they can also choose not to eat it. However, if they eat with doubt, it becomes a sin for them.

@VincentWong It was clearly an issue in Galatians 2. In Romans it's important to distinguish between Jewish Christians and Jews who were not Christians. Not to mention Acts 21 where Paul agrees to participate in a Temple ceremony in order to prove that " you yourself live in observance of the law." Personally I doubt that Paul would have agreed to this stipulation. One of many examples of difficulties in what Paul himself writes and what Luke reports him to have said.

According to my understanding in Romans 14, Paul primary concern is faith in Jesus. He considered everything are secondary. Therefore, he did not object to Jewish Christians maintaining their tradition, as long as they did not place these traditions above faith in Jesus Christ.
